# Rotations of dyadic tensors

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, tensor-products, rotations, tensors

The following is stated in a text I am using regarding **rotations of cartesian tensors**: A Cartesian tensor of rank 2 is a dyadic formed out of two vectors $U$ and $V$. One simply takes a Cartesian component of $U$ and a Cartesian component of $V$ and puts them together $$T_{ij} := U_{i}V_{j}.$$ Cartesian tensor like this is *reducible*-that is, it can be decomposed into objects that transform differently under rotations. Specifically, for the dyadic above we have $$U_iV_j = \frac{U \cdot V}{3} \delta_{ij} + \frac{(U_i V_j - U_j V_i)}{2} + \bigg( \frac{U_i V_j + U_j V_i}{2} - \frac{U \cdot V}{3} \delta_{ij } \bigg)$$

**Question:**
How does it follow that the second term can be written as $\epsilon_{ijk}(U \times V)_{k}$ and how does this imply that it has 3 independent components?

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: Have you tried to expand $\epsilon_{ijk}(U \times V)_k$?

Comment: @md2perpe Yes I have I get $(U \times V)_k = \langle U_j V_k-U_kV_j, U_kV_i-U_iV_k, U_iV_j-U_jV_i \rangle_{k} = U_iV_j-UjV_i$, how the Levi-Civita function is used to get $\frac{U_iV_j-UjV_i}{2}$ I'm not sure, and how this implies 3 independent components?

Comment: We have $U \times V = (U_2 V_3 - U_3 V_2, U_3 V_1 - U_1 V_3, U_1 V_2 - U_2 V_1)$, so for example $(U \times V)_1 = U_2 V_3 - U_3 V_2$. Compare this to $\epsilon_{23k}(U \times V)_k = \epsilon_{231}(U \times V)_1 = (+1) \cdot (U_2 V_3 - U_3 V_2) = U_2 V_3 - U_3 V_2$, i.e. (at least for $i=2$, $j=3$) we have $\epsilon_{ijk}(U \times V) = U_i V_j - U_j V_i$.

Comment: Since $U \times V$ is a 3-vector, it has 3 components, and so does $U_i V_j - U_j V_i$.

Comment: @md2perpe Are the components explicilty given as  $(U_iV_j-U_jV_i, U_kV_i-U_iV_k,U_jV_k-U_kV_j)$?

Comment: The components of $U \times V$ are $(U_2 V_3 - U_3 V_2, U_3 V_1 - U_1 V_3, U_1 V_2 - U_2 V_1)$, and this can be written $(U \times V)_i = \epsilon_{ijk} U_j V_k$.